# How to use the file content to rename multiple files

Tags: python, python-2.7, rename, listdir

I have two files (Running-2015-01-01.txt and Running-2015-01-02.txt), with a device hostname information on each file. My goal is to rename those files with stripping "Running" and replace it with the device hostname from the file content.

This is what I have so far. The interpreter doesn't shows any error, but nothing happens to my target files:

```
for filename in glob.glob("Running*"):
    selected_file = open(filename, "r").readlines()
    for i, s in enumerate(filename):
        if "hostname" in filename:
            hostname_file = str(filename[i][8:]).strip()
            os.rename(filename, hostname_file + filename[7:])
```

I also created separate functions to rename the file and collect the content information from the file and they work.

collect info from the file content

```
def collect_string():
    filename = raw_input("Enter your filename : ")
    selected_file = open(filename, "r")
    line = selected_file.readlines()
    date_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    for i, s in enumerate(line):
        if "hostname" in s:
            output = str(line[i][8:]).strip()
            print output
```

rename file

```
def rename_file():
    for filename in os.listdir("."):
        if filename.startswith("Running"):
            os.rename(filename, "Config" + filename[6:])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `collect_string` function, you test if "hostname" is in the lines of the file, which works. In your first function, you test if it's in the filename, which of course don't work.

Also, you don't need to use `enumerate`. You can loop through a list just fine with the syntax `for element in myList`, as in your function `rename_file`.

Finally to avoid confusion, I suggest to use clearer variable names.

Here's your code fixed (but not tested):

```
def rename():
  for filename in glob.glob("Running*"):
    newName=collect_hostname(filename)+ filename[7:]
    os.rename(filename,newName)

def collect_hostname(filename)
    with open(filename) as f:     #best practice to open a file
      for line in f:
        if "hostname" in line:
          return line[8:].strip() #line is already a string, no need for str
```